# Display text before header() file download

Tags: php, header

I need to display a text before I do header() redirection to push file for download. So, for example

```
echo "text";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

while (!feof($handle)) {
   echo fgets($handle, $chunksize);
   flush();
}
fclose($handle);
```

Is that doable?

Comment: perhaps it's a duplicate but the other thread wouldn't give me an answer - I can't use META REFRESH in this case

Comment: There's no shortage of [other duplicate questions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+php+display+page+and+download+file&aq=f&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+php+display+page+and+download+file&aqs=chrome.0.57j58.10495j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that differently. Set up a simple page with your text displayed and redirect the user to the download page thanks to a javascript or HTML redirect. Usually the browser will show the download prompt in a new window and your text will still be displayed.